# React useParams undefined for editing user profile

Tags: reactjs, react-router, fetch, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Looked at the other posts about params, but I'm not having luck.

I have a user profile that when clicked on, shows the metadata from the user, and has an edit button to change the nickname key value.

My useParams nickname comes back undefined.

I know this is a lot of code,, I've been sitting at this computer for too long, and can't figure this out right now.

**my Profile/index.js**

```
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ProfileInfo = ({ label, value }) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object')
        value = (
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(value).map((key) => {
                    return (
                        <ProfileInfo key={key} label={key} value={value[key]} />
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    else value = value.toString();
    return (
        <li>
            <strong>{label}</strong>: <span>{value}</span>
        </li>
    );
};

ProfileInfo.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.number,
        PropTypes.bool,
        PropTypes.object
    ])
};

const Profile = () => {
    const { nickname } = useParams()
    const [user, setUser] = useState({nickname: "Not Sure"});
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState (true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const getUser = async () => {
            const url = `/profile/${nickname}`
            const res = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
                signal: abortController.signal
            });
            if (res.ok && !abortController.signal.aborted) {
                const data = await res.json();
                setUser(data);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };
        getUser();
        return function cleanup() {
            abortController.abort();
        };
    }, [nickname]);

    return isLoading ? (
        'Loading...'
    ) :  (
        <>
            <h2>Profile</h2>
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(user).map((key) => {
                    return (
                        <ProfileInfo key={key} label={key} value={user[key]} />
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
            <Link to={`/edit-user/${nickname}`}>Edit</Link>
        </>
    );
};

export default Profile;
```

**my ProfileForm/index.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProfileForm = () => {
    const form = useRef(null);
    const { nickname } = useParams();
    const history = useHistory();
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        if (event.target.value.trim() === '') return;
        setUser({
            ...user,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    };

    const save = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation && event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("save: " + user.nickname);
        const method = user.nickname ? 'PUT' : 'POST';
        const url = user.nickname ? `/profile/${nickname}` : '/profile';

        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user),
            signal: abortController.signal
        });
        if (res.ok && !abortController.signal.aborted) {
            const result = await res.json();
            history.push(`/edit-user/${result.nickname}`);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        form.current.reset();
        if (nickname) {
            const abortController = new AbortController();
            const getUser = async () => {
                const url = `/profile/${nickname}`;
                const res = await fetch(url, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
                    signal: abortController.signal
                });
                if (res.ok && !abortController.signal.aborted) {
                    const result = await res.json();
                    setUser(result);
                }
            };

            getUser();
            return function cleanup() {
                abortController.abort();
            };
        }
    }, [nickname]);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={save} ref={form}>
            <div>
                <label>
                    Display Name
                    <br />
                    <input
                        name={'title'}
                        type="text"
                        defaultValue={user.title}
                        onBlur={handleChange}
                        required
                    />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div> 
        </form>
    );
};

export default ProfileForm;
```

**my Appframe/index.js**

```
import './AppFrame.css';

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import loadable from '@loadable/component';

import Header from '../Header';

/* istanbul ignore next */
const Rooms = loadable(() => import('../Rooms'));

/* istanbul ignore next */
const Room = loadable(() => import('../Room'));

/* istanbul ignore next */
const RoomForm = loadable(() => import('../RoomForm'));

/* instanbul ignore next */
const Profile = loadable(() => import('../Profile'));

/* instanbul ignore next */
const ProfileForm = loadable(() => import('../ProfileForm'))

const AppFrame = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Header />
            <nav className="app-navigation">
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/rooms">Room List</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/create-room">Create a room</NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
            <Route path="/r/:code" exact component={Room} />
            <Route path="/rooms" component={Rooms} />
            <Route path="/create-room" exact component={RoomForm} />
            <Route path="/edit-room/:code" exact component={RoomForm} />
            <Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile} />
            <Route path="/edit-user/:nickname" exact component={ProfileForm} />
        </Router>
    );
};

export default AppFrame;
```

**my user json data**

```
{
active: false
code: "y5bJUwc4Ho"
createdAt: "2020-05-16T18:02:16.430Z"
nickname: "Miles Davis"
online: true
updatedAt: "2020-05-16T18:02:16.430Z"
__v: 0
_id: "3839383838"
__proto__: Object
}
```

**the error I get**

```
index.js?d113:43 GET https://localhost:7000/profile/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I'm noticing when i reference /profile/user.nickname  I start to see my catch user nickname, but it doesn't effectively go through the useEffect fetch in Profile/index.js. 
Feel like I'm getting closer.

Comment: I'm having the same problem , useParams() is returning undefined despite a param added where /:pathparam is set in the Route's path attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed adding the `nickname` param to the path, in Appframe/index.js.
Change:

```
<Route path="/profile/:nickname" exact component={Profile} />
```

To:

```
<Route path="/profile/:nickname" exact component={Profile} />
```

And in ProfileForm under useEffect update to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    form.current.reset();
    const {nickname} = useParams();
    if (nickname) {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const getUser = async () => {
            const url = `/profile/${nickname}`;
            const res = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
                signal: abortController.signal
            });
            if (res.ok && !abortController.signal.aborted) {
                const result = await res.json();
                setUser(result);
            }
        };

        getUser();
        return function cleanup() {
            abortController.abort();
        };
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: are you saying to add that route as opposed to the /edit-user/:nickname route that is there at the moment?  Or add /:nickname to the current path="/profile"?

Comment: I've tried a couple of edits in regards to this statement, and changing where I referenced path /edit-user/, but still getting the same undefined error.  
I'm stuck in the 'Loading ...' screen.  I'm looking at the if statement in the ProfileForm under useEffect(), it could be erroring there.

Comment: Thank you for updating and keeping up with this issue with me, but so far I'm still getting the same error with these changes you suggest.  I'm at the url:
https://localhost:7000/profile
and the error is:
GET https://localhost:7000/profile/undefined 404 (Not Found)  
It's not a post error, because It fails in Profile, but I can get to the post error, if i move things around, but ultimately the issue is useParams isn't recognizing nickname as a param within /profile/  but it definitely is.  
/profile/undefined seems to keep holding me up.  I've taken /edit-user/ out of all files.

Comment: when I fetch from just '/profile' and make no reference to params,  I get that snippet "my user json data'.    and nickname is a top level key in that object.  so it should be easy to be referenced with the syntax I'm using.  I know the error is one of these files.  It's a very bare bones app at the moment.

Comment: When you want to access nickname as a url param, you will have to open a url like:
localhost:7000/profile/vader, in this case value of nickname will be vader in ProfileForm.

Comment: As per what you have described, if data can be fetched from /profile directly then you might want to make a fetch call directly to /profile.

Change `const url = `/profile/${nickname}`` to `const url = `/profile/`` in the ProfileForm -> useEffect()

Comment: Uhhh, I don't see a difference between your two routes.
Change [from] is exactly the same as [to].

Comment: how you used useParams() in useEffect which React Hook "useParams" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.